# Using copies of global variables in functions

Tags: javascript, function, global-variables, local-variables

Consider I have a global variable called `generatedPattern`. I want to use it in a `function animate()`, but do not want to change its value. So I copy generatedPattern to a local var(say `var patternToAnimate`) in the function and then use patternToAnimate.

Will any change to patternToAnimate change generatedPattern? If so, how do I avoid this?

I.e., how do I use generatedPattern in a function locally without changing it globally?

#### Code

```
function animateGeneratedPattern() {

    var patternToAnimate = generatedPattern;

    function animateNextPattern(lightup) {
        if (!patternToAnimate|| patternToAnimate.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        switch(patternToAnimate[0]) {
            case 1:
                animateRed();
                break;
            case 2:
                animateGreen();
                break;
            case 3:
                animateBlue();
                break;
             case 4:
                animateYellow();
                break;
        }

        if (lightup) {
            // Long delay before turning light off
            setTimeout(function() {
                animateNextPattern(false);
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            patternToAnimate.splice(0, 1);
            // Small delay before turning on next light
            setTimeout(function() {
                animateNextPattern(true);
            }, 10);
        }
    }
    animateNextPattern(true);
}
```

When patternToAnimate gets spliced, so does generatedPattern.

Comment: it depends if `generatedPattern` is a primitive value or not.

Comment: Globally it is defined as var generatedPattern=[];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use and alter `generatedPattern` somewhere else, well, it gets changed.

If you want to use the values of `genratedPattern` in another function without modifying it, you indeed have to copy it. But beware, don't save it as a reference:

```
var generatedPattern = [1, 2, 3];
var patternToAnimate = generatedPattern;
```

Here, `patternToAnimate` is a reference to `generatedPattern`. So when you modify `patternToAnimate` `generatedPattern` gets modified as well. As they are literally the same arrays.

If you want to copy one array to another, use `slice`

```
var generatedPattern = [1, 2, 3];
var patternToAnimate = generatedPattern.slice();
```

Now `patternToAnimate` is a new, copy of `generatedPattern` which can be modified without modifying the original array.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kx7f766w/1/

Comment: So if I do `var patternToAnimate=generatedPattern;` inside a function, they both reference the same array??

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the global variable to a new variable within a lower scope:

```js
console.clear();
console.log('no problem')
var global = 123;
(function () {
  var local = global;
  local = 321;
  console.log("local is",local);
})();
console.log("global is",global);
console.log('Actually change the global variable')
global = 123;
(function () {
  global = 321;
})();
console.log("global is",global);
```

Local scope variables won't leak back to your global variables.

Comment: Thats what I tried, but when I change the local var, the global one also changes.

Comment: Please post a code example so i can see what goes on